# Split string into list by line separator?

Tags: java, split

For the string

```
String cow = "A cow jumped \n over the \n moon."
```

How can I split the string into a list?

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(test, cow).split("\n"));
```

The code above is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
String cow = "A cow jumped \n over the \n moon.";
List<String> test = Arrays.asList(cow.split("\n"));
```

Comment: Or, `cow.split("\\s+\n\\s+")` to `trim` with the regex.

Comment: nice one Elliot